# Nginx Redirect https to non-www not working

Tags: redirect, nginx

I've looked on Stack Overflow and other sites but cannot seem to get this redirect working. Everything is working as expected, except:

The following work:

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

This does NOT redirect to the non-www (it keeps the www in place):

```
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

Both the www and non-www https versions seem resolve as is. Any ideas?

Here is the current config:

```
# Redirect WWW to NON-WWW
server {
    # Server host
    server_name www.example.com;

    # Server ports
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Redirect
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
server {
    # Server host
    server_name example.com;

    # Server port
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Redirect
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

# Main Block
server {
    # Server host
    server_name example.com;

    # Server port
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
     }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to have `ssl` switched on in your first server block.

Comment: @RichardSmith when you say switched on what do you mean? In the first server block I'm listening on port 443 and have the ssl certs - is there more I need to add?

Comment: Wait, why do you want to redirect `https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com`?  Did you mean `https://www.example.com -> https://example.com`?  Moreover, i believe Richard Smith means [ssl on;](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl).

Comment: @grochmal correct! I just fixed that in my post!

Comment: @grochmal I added the ssl on; and fixed a syntax error on the ssl ciphers in the last block and all works! Thanks to you both!

Comment: In a mixed ssl/non-ssl server block you need to use the ssl suffix on the listen directive. Otherwise with "ssl on" you get ssl on port 80 too. See this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html